# Composition of conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Suppose that $X, Y, Z$ are events. Prove or provide a counterexample:
$$P(Y \vert X) \cdot P(Z \vert Y) \leq P(Z \vert X)$$

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried applying Bayes rule a million which ways. Starting to think it's not true, but I think the statement is intuitively true...

Comment: Suppose $Y$ always happens and that $Z=X^c$.

Comment: and to maximise the difference make $P(X,Y,Z^c)=\delta$ and $P(X^c,Y,Z)=1-\delta$  for very small positive delta

Comment: Two independent coin throws. $X$: first throw is "heads". $Y$: second throw is "heads". $Z$: first throw is "tails". (This is @lulu 's example, tweaked and elaborated.)